# Fetching diferent servers at the same time to create a component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a modular system that makes sure it has access to the other servers on my front end app. I'm fetching all of them inside a forEach loop and then trying to update the useState() just adding the "new component". What Am I doing wrong?

In less words, trying to insert the new component at the end of the previous created ones.

```
const [dropdownItems, setdropdownItems] = useState([])

session.reachablePartner.forEach((serverPartner)=>{
    fetch(`http://${serverPartner.ipAddress}/api/isonline`).then((res)=>{
      setdropdownItems(...dropdownItems,<DropDownItem
        key={serverPartner.ipAddress}
        onClick={() => {
          window.location.replace(`http://${serverPartner.ipAddress}/`)
          
        }}
      >
        {serverPartner.serverName}
      </DropDownItem>)
    }).catch(()=>{
      console.log(serverPartner.serverName + " Is not reachable")
    })
  })
```

Comment: (1) Don't put components (esp. with callbacks) in state, just put pure data there (2) You'd have a better time if each partner was a separate component that checks the component's onlineness and renders an item if they're online, or null if they're not.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now, here is the final code if some one needs it.

**Code:**

```
 useEffect(()=>{

    (async()=>{


      const promises = session.reachablePartner.map((serverPartner)=>{
        return fetch(`http://${serverPartner.ipAddress}/api/isonline`).then(reply=>reply).catch(err=>console.log(err))
      })


      Promise.all(promises).then(result=>{

        const linkstoShow = session.reachablePartner.filter((link,index)=>result[index])
        setdropdownItems(linkstoShow.map(serverPartner=>{
          <DropDownItem
          key={serverPartner.ipAddress}
          onClick={() => {
            window.location.replace(`http://${serverPartner.ipAddress}/`)
            
          }}
        >
          {serverPartner.serverName}
        </DropDownItem>
        }))
      })
    })()

  },[])
```